# Creating an RSS/XML datasource

Tags: cakephp, rss, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create a feeds data source to make getting feeds easier and cleaner, and as a way to learn some new bits and bobs of the Cake framework.

I have the datasource working as I'd like, it returns items, however I'd like to be able to instantiate it with different feeds so that I don't need to create a new data source for each feed. I'm going to be syndicating about 5 different feeds.

I was thinking about defining them in the `app/config/core.php` and then passing in which one you wanted as a condition in the find, but I'd rather do it lower down than in the controller.

Any idea's please?

Uploaded my code here, https://bitbucket.org/davidyell/cakephp-feedsource/src/4010d393af1b/FeedSource.php

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is.

Comment: It's more of a best practise question I think. Having talked it over with developer mates it seems more logical to have a fat model with additional functions in and the datasource simply returns the whole feed.

Comment: Why not to use datasources configuration array? http://book.cakephp.org/view/1077/An-Example something like.. `var $rss = array('datasource' => 'rss','feeds' => array('http://feed1.com', 'http://feed2.com'));`

Answer (score 1):

Datasources usually pick up configuration settings from the DATABASE_CONFIG class. You could define the rss urls there or pass a parameter from your Model to the Datasource. Take a look at [LoadSys' RSS Datasource](https://github.com/loadsys/CakePHP-RSS-Datasource) to give you some hints as to what would be a good way to do this.